# FedEx api for shipping

Tags: fedex

I want to apply FedEx API in my e-commerce website.
but I did't know how to apply that API.
I have done "Test Key registration" and get Test Account information.
so what I am doing next.

Thanks

Comment: "I want to apply FedEx API in my e-commerce website".. can you please specifiy: how? which function are you try to activate? can you provide some links to fedex api docs? (because the docs areto be locked without registration)

Answer (score 3):

The following answer is concerning the tracking service which is part of the shipping services:
After receiving your test credentials (key, password, account number and meter number), use them to send SOAP requests (as you normally do using your programming language) to the service at https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/track
Use 123456789012 as a test tracking number.
When you are ready to move to the production environment, change the service path to https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/track (or https://gateway.fedex.com:443/web-services/track) and use the production credentials that can be obtained [from here](https://www.fedex.com/wpor/web/jsp/drclinks.jsp?links=wss/production.html)

Please refer to [the documentation](http://images.fedex.com/us/developer/product/WebServices/MyWebHelp/DeveloperGuide2012.pdf) to be informed on how to use the services with your programming language.

Comment: Please have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27918274/fed-ex-tracking-api-shows-un-expected-behaviour-using-testing-web-service-url-an

Answer (score 1):

According to FedEx, they are retiring their API soon.  I believe the target date is the end of May, 2012.  Now they are going to web services instead of an API.  Here is more on the announcement:

http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/migration.html

As far as the web services are concerned, they have good documentation on their site for both how to access the web services directly and how to put a widget on your site that will allow a customer to look up their shipping.  Here are those resources:

http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/solutions.html

There are also demos and tutorials here:

http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/web-services/index.html

I hope that helps you get started.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel you are ready to test live shipments you wil now need to contact the fedex help desk and ask to get a user key that will be associated with your fedex account. 
The test key only gets you to the testing side of web services. To get real rates and such you will need to point to the live gateway using a real user key.