# Fed Ex tracking API shows un-expected behaviour using testing web service url and credentials

Tags: web-services, fedex

I have a question related with Fed Ex Tracking API. First of all I am using ***FedEx testing URL and credential*** which we generate for development. I am not using production creadential and URL. 
Basically ***I wanted to know limitation of fed ex testing credential and url***. Actually I got a problem and not able to get answer of that problem neither in document nor by googling. 
I track the shipment via tracking number using fedex tracking web service(***using testing URL and credential***), Initially they shows the result but after sometime they stopped showing result and I get message in response that tracking number not found but when I used same tracking number on fed ex website then on there it shows the correct result. I don't know why it is behaving like this. Another thing for some tracking number it shows the result and for some it does not show. So anyone guide me in right direction.

Thanks,
Awadhendra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this problem. Actually there is no confusion in behaviour of fedex services. Actually I am using specific service which is for ground service only and tracking number which I am using is not for ground service. Thats why I am facing problem. Second thing I am using v9 fedex tracking service, I changed it from v9 to v6 service and it works.

Thanks.

Comment: Recently went through the same set of issues myself... I haven't seen any outright wrong data but I'm still using v9 with no problems.  Actually I just instantiated my interface directly from their wsdl file.  What I did was batch my tracking numbers by shipping type (obtained from a local database), translated the local shipping info to 'FDXE' or 'FDXG' (express or ground services, there are a few others as well if you need them) and then set up my queries to contain tracking numbers of only one specific carrier code each. For an unknown number I know no better than just trial & error, sadly.

Answer (score 2):

If your using your own live/production tracking number in the FedEx test environment note that their testing environment only retains tracking data for a few months.  Anything beyond that will return an error that the package information is not available even though you can still track it successfully in production.

Here’s a list of static tracking numbers that can be used in the FedEx test environment:

```
449044304137821 = Shipment information sent to FedEx
149331877648230 = Tendered
020207021381215 = Picked Up
403934084723025 = Arrived at FedEx location
920241085725456 = At local FedEx facility
568838414941 = At destination sort facility
039813852990618 = Departed FedEx location
231300687629630 = On FedEx vehicle for delivery
797806677146 = International shipment release
377101283611590 = Customer not available or business closed
852426136339213 = Local Delivery Restriction
797615467620 = Incorrect Address
957794015041323 = Unable to Deliver
076288115212522 = Returned to Sender/Shipper
581190049992 = International Clearance delay
122816215025810 = Delivered
843119172384577 = Hold at Location
070358180009382 = Shipment Canceled
```

The above list of tracking numbers will work when pointed to the following server endpoint:

https://wsbeta.fedex.com:443/web-services/track

Note that the only time these numbers will not work is during FedEx's scheduled maintenance windows.

Answer (score 0):

For testing you can use these tracking numbers 111111111111 or 123456789012.

When you use Live Tracking numbers with Testing Credentials, there are some confusions like you said.